# Error with Nvidia 410.78 drivers

Tags: nvidia

Just updated from Nvidia 410.73 to 410.78 drivers.  410.73 ran fine.  Now 410.78 throws an error when trying to use nvidia-settings.

```
root@Serenity:/home/keith/Desktop# /usr/bin/nvidia-settings
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

(nvidia-settings:3214): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:49:45.561: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
** Message: 16:49:46.239: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 16:49:46.239: PRIME: is it supported? no
^C
root@Serenity:/home/keith/Desktop#
```

So what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Yes several times. Each time I tried to use nvidia-settings for setting my clocks and fan speeds, the command were not accepted.

Comment: I then tried to revert to 396 drivers and hit the same problem.  So I backed out of the Nvidia drivers entirely and reverted to base Nouveau drivers.  Then went back to 410.78 drivers as the ppa doesn't offer the 410.73 release anymore. I can now actually invoke the nvidia-settings parameters and they are at least accepted.  Just have a benign libEGL failed to authenticate error still.

Comment: I can't find any mention of this new error with this driver on the Ubuntu forums.  I shot an email off to one of the ppa maintainers and hope to hear something from him eventually.

Comment: I just use the normal Additional Drivers tab installation in the Software Updater to install the drivers.  Been doing it since 390 with no issues.  I tried the 415.13 drivers when they were released but they were MUCH slower than the 410.73 drivers so I reverted.  I use the Nvidia drivers for distributed processing.  No graphics or gaming. Been running with no issues on Nvidia ppa drivers for a year.  It was just this last minor update that things went wrong.

Comment: No I don't normally just invoke nvidia-settings without parameters.  I just did that for a quick test to see if the bug was still there after all the downgrades/upgrades. The very first attempt to run my nvidia-settings script after installing the 410.78 drivers failed on every parameter call with the libEGL failed to authenticate error.  Why I had to start looking for the reason for the change in the new driver that I had never had any problem with before on earlier drivers.  So I had to jump through hoops to get a working system again.

Comment: Or that is the first part of the script.  It looks like there is a comment limit here. Each nvidia-settings parameter call had the error printed after the call.  I checked the cards and none of the parameters were correctly invoked.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome Desktop

Comment: This is the part of the script.#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GPUPowerMizerMode=1"
/usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:1]/GPUPowerMizerMode=1"
/usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:2]/GPUPowerMizerMode=1"

/usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=800" -a "[gpu:0]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=30"
/usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:1]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=800" -a "[gpu:1]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=30"
/usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:2]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=2000" -a "[gpu:2]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=30"